# SSRS 2005 Multi Value Parameters with Covering Index

Tags: sql, reporting-services, indexing, reportingservices-2005

Morning All,

I am currently attempting to implement multi valued parameters in SQL2005 / SSRS2005

I have went about this in the way suggested in many blogs / walk throughs, using an expression to comma seperate the parameters like so:

`=Join(Parameters! <ParameterName> .Value,", ")`

I then use a function to split out the parameters.

```
WHERE 
close_date BETWEEN @FROMCLOSEDATE AND @TOCLOSEDATE
AND (Group_ID IN (SELECT Val from dbo.fn_String_To_Table(@RESGROUP,',',1)))
```

This now works as expected. The Stored Procedure is searching 1.4 million rows to find dates between the parameters and `IN RESGROUP`, this takes a very long time, so it would be best if an index was used. From what I gather the index isn't used because of the Table Valued Functions.

Is there anything else I can do to improve performance in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the return values from the function into a temp table and use that in the query and see the performace.

Other wise you can try dynamic query.